# Syntax error near unexpected token 'then' in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting and this is my first shell script.i am getting this error and stuck in it.following is the simple code for it:

```
#!/bin/sh
yes=y;
no=n;
echo "Do you want to enter batch order id manually? (y/n) "
read answer
if [ $answer -eq $yes ]; then
    echo "Please Enter Batch Order Id."
elif[ $answer -eq $no ]; then
    echo "Copying all batch orders."
else
    echo"please enter correct input."
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script needs a couple minor changes:

```
#!/bin/sh
yes=y;
no=n;
echo "Do you want to enter batch order id manually? (y/n) "
read answer
if [ "$answer" = $yes ]; then
    echo "Please Enter Batch Order Id."
elif [ "$answer" = $no ]; then
    echo "Copying all batch orders."
else
    echo "please enter correct input."
fi
```

A space is needed after `elif` and before `[ $answer -eq $no ]`.
 The tests make string comparisons, not numeric comparisons.  So, `=` is needed in place of `-eq`.  So that the script works even if the user enters nothing, `$answer` is placed inside double-quotes in the tests.  Also, a space is required between `echo` and `"please enter correct input."`.

Comment: yes,it worked.Thanks but i want to know why it was showing error for then?can you please explain

Comment: It was the lack of a space after `elif` that confused bash leading to the unexpected `then` error.

Comment: More specifically, `[` is not part of `bash`'s syntax; it's a command name (an alias for the `test` command), so `bash` doesn't consider `elif[` to be the word `elif` followed by a `[`; it's a single word `elif[`.